# Decorator feature not working (unexpected token)

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-next

Just tried to use  decorators in React:

```
import React from 'react';
import Fade from './Transitions/Fade'
import withVisible from './withVisible'

@withVisible()
const App = props =>
    <Fade visible={props.visible} duration={500}>
        Hello
    </Fade>

export default App
```

If I use the common way ( withVisible()(App) ) then it's working properly.
(My guess is that NodeJS can't compile my code with the @ ) [Syntax error: Unexpected token (@) ]

```
import React from 'react'

const withVisible = () => Component =>
    class WithVisible extends React.Component {
        state = {
            visible: true
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <Component visible={this.state.visible} {...this.props}/>
            )
        }
    }

export default withVisible
```

Comment: this might be helpful: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-es2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your .babelrc do not have added decorator plugin.
Try this: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators

Answer (score 1):

You need [transform-decorators-legacy](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/) babel plugin to make this syntax work.