# Are Decorators allowed in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, javascript-decorators

I'm trying to run the following code in NodeJS using terminal

```
function addStringToName(target, name, descriptor) {
    const fn = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = wrestler => {
        fn.call(target, wrestler + ' is a wrestler');
    };
}

class Wrestler {
    @addStringToName
    setName(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    sayName() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

const w = new Wrestler();
w.setName('Macho Man');
w.sayName();
```

Getting the following error

[image: Error]

Can Decorators be used in NodeJS if yes what is wrong with the written code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decorator feature not working (unexpected token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257334/decorator-feature-not-working-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no. You have to use TypeScript in order to have decorators enabled. Moreover, even TypeScript doesn't support it natively. You will have to have `target: "ES5"` at least and `"experimentalDecorators": true`.

You can find more about decorators and TypeScript here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: You don't have to have TypeScript; decorators are experimental for JS too https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

Comment: It's a proposal mate. Neither I nor this feature developers would recommend using that feature yet. Check this out https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#how-should-i-use-decorators-in-transpilers-today

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But they're experimental/a proposal in **both JS *and* TS**, whereas your answer incorrectly states *"you have to use TypeScript"*.